# Is it correct to use "in regards to"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

"In regards to" is something I use constantly. I use that to refer back to a specific subject or object.

For example:

> A: Is it too expensive? Also, would I be able to make an appointment?
>   B: It is not that expensive in comparison to other services. **In regards to** the appointment, yes! You will be able to make one whenever you're ready.

I have found that other alternatives include:

- As regards
- Regarding
- With regards to
- In regard

Are all of those, including "in regards to", grammatically correct?

Comment: The most common way of saying this (in my experience) is “As far as . . .” and you could add “goes” as a sort of end-bracket if you wanted to, like “**As far as** the appointment **goes,** yes!” It sounds strange if you think of each word functioning literally, but I promise you this is a legitimate (though somewhat casual) speech pattern in modern English.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Regard* is tricky. The ‘rules’ below are those observed in formal writing; you may safely ignore them in conversation.

When used as a noun to express your attention to a particular topic, it should be used in the **singular**:

> In **regard** to the appointment, yes!  ... not *regards*.
>   With **regard** to the appointment, yes!  ... not *regards*.

This is often confused, even (or perhaps *particularly*) by native speakers with the related phrase *as regard**s***:

> As **regards** the appointment, yes!

This is not a plural, however, but a 3d person singular verb; the sense is that your discourse now *regards* (“looks back to”, “contemplates”) the noun or NP which follows. The verb sense is also used in the present participle *regarding*:

> **Regarding** the appointment, yes!

The plural noun *regards* is used only in the sense “expression of esteem or affection”. In this sense the plural varies freely with the singular.

> Please convey my very sincere **regards** [or **regard**] to your mother.
>   “Give my **Regards** to Broadway” —song by George M. Cohan

In the sense of “esteem, honor, opinion”, however, only the singular is ordinarily employed.

> I hold him in the highest **regard**.

*Respect*, which also acts as both a noun and a verb, works exactly the same way in these senses.

> With **respect** to ...
>   With **regard** to ...
>   As **respects** ...
>   **Respecting** ...
>   Convey my **respects** to ...

Both words have other senses, however, in which their use varies.

Comment: +1 This answer is so good in so many ways... a hat tip, Sir!

Comment: Oh my... this is a brilliant answer. My *regards*, @StoneyB! (see what I did there?)